# How to append list in list in python3?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

```
def cal(i,L,cset,comp):
    for n in range(i,len(L)):
        print(cset+[L[1]])
        comp.insert(cset+[L(n)])
        cal(i+1,L,comp[len(comp)-1],comp)
    return comp
print(cal(0,[1,2,3,4,5],[],[]))
```

in this code it gives me an error from the first iterration

line 4, in cal

comp.insert(cset+[L(n)])

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

I did change 
comp.insert(cset+[L(n)])
to
comp.insert(cset+[L[n]])
Just got lost there :/